# Why is the linear approximation of my function, after I remove negligible terms, more accurate than the linear approximation not removing the terms?

Tags: calculus, linear-approximation

I have the function $ F(x) $ where $ x >> a $ and I have derived two linear approximations of $ F(x) $:

- $ L_{1}(x) $, where I take that $ \frac{\left(a^{2}-2xa\right)}{x^{2}} $ is way way less than 1 (and therefore, $ (1+x)^{m} \approx 1+mx $ )
- $ L_{2}(x) $, where I say that $ a^2 $ is negligible as is very small compared to $ x^2 $ and after discarding it I take the binomial approximation in the same way I did in $ L_{1} $

I'm quite surprised that discarding $ a^2 $ and doing the approximation leaves me with a better function (when x is very big) than if I don't do it. Is there any explanation for it?

$$ F\left(x\right)=\left(1+\frac{\left(a^{2}-2xa\right)}{x^{2}}\right)^{\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)}\left\{x>0\right\} \\
L_1\left(x\right)=\left(1+\frac{1}{2}\frac{\left(a^{2}-2xa\right)}{x^{2}}\right)\left\{x>0\right\} \\
L_2\left(x\right)=\left(1+\frac{1}{2}\frac{\left(-2xa\right)}{x^{2}}\right)\left\{x>0\right\}
$$

[image]
https://www.desmos.com/calculator/zty1n9upqr

Comment: The removed term is only negligible for large $x,$ where $L_1$ works well (though of course not as well as the exact equivalent formula for $x > a$). At $x=a$ the removed term is not "negligible" at all.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$F(x) = |\frac{x-a}{x}|$ and $L_2(x) = \frac{x-a}{x}$, so $L_2$ is not an approximation of $F$, it is **equal to** $F$ for $x \geq a$.

Basically what you have done in $L_2$ gives you the equality thanks to the simplification of the square with the square root. Indeed if instead you use for example $$ F'\left(x\right)=\left(1+\frac{\left(a^{2}-2xa\right)}{x^{2}}\right)^{\color{red}{3}} $$ where there is no simplification involved, you will see that $L'_1$ is better than $L'_2$ for large $x$.